# C++: Getting character codes instead of letters when writing data to rich text box Text property

Tags: c++, string, vector, char, ascii

I am new to C++ and working on a relatively ambitious Win32 application in Visual Studio. The problem I'm having is that a text field in the main window is displaying a number instead of a letter when 'writing' from a string.

I'm reading a vector into a Rich Text Box, but instead of AA, the text box displays 6565. I understand that 65 is the character code for 'A', but haven't been able to find how to get the window to display the letter.

This is the code that creates the vector. Debugging this piece shows that the data loads properly. This snippet of code is part of a 'portfolio' class.

```
vector<string> tickers;
string cell;
string line;

ifstream d ("file.csv"); //The file contents look like: AA,AAPL,BAC and so on

if (d.is_open()) {

    getline(d,line);
    stringstream line2(line);

    for (ci=0; ci<c; ci++) { //c is known and is the number of 'columns' in the file I am reading.
      getline(line2,cell,',');
      tickers.push_back(cell);
    }
}
```

The rich text box's name is "Results2".
The code to set the Text property of the rich text box is:

```
portfolio p;
int n = p.tickers.size();

for (int i=0; i<n; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<p.tickers[i].size(); j++) {
        Results2->Text += p.tickers[i][j];
    }
    Results2->Text += "\n";
}
```

I know that the "Results2->Text" bit is correct, because the data is getting there just fine. The problem is, I end up with:

6565
65658076

instead of:

AA
AAPL

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Need to know what kind of object `Results2->Text` is.

Comment: Is the output '6565 65658076' coming out in the console or the debugger? That is, is it being stored as a load of `int`s, or is the output function just displaying them as `int`s for some reason?

Comment: I missed `string cell;`

Comment: I added the `string cell;` and `string line;` code. The 6565 65658076 is in the window the the application generates (it's a lot of code, so I didn't include that stuff. Also, Results2 is `System::Windows::Forms::RichTextBox`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be a Marshalling issue between your C++/STL string you are manipulating and C++/CLI String that the RichTextBox is taking.

**EDIT**

The problem is that you are putting the characters one by one in the `RichTextBox::Text`, or this field expect a `System::String` so it convert each character as an integer value to a `String` before putting it in the textbox, that's why you get the ASCII numbers instead of the string.

Since `portfolio::tickers` is a  `vector<std::string>` as you specify in the comment, you could convert each `std::string` to a `char*` before giving it to the `RichTextBox::Text` :

```
portfolio p;
for (int i=0; i<p.tickers.size(); i++) {
    Results2->Text += gcnew String(p.tickers[i].c_str());
    Results2->Text += "\n";
}
```

You could also use the `marshal_as`introduced in VC2008 :

```
Results2->Text += marshal_as<String^>(p.tickers[i].c_str());
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! `portfolio::tickers` is a `vector<string>` (in the first block of code I posted). The reason I have two indices is that I was going through the debugger and saw that the data in the tickers vector is stored like: `tickers[0][0] = 65 'A'` `tickers[0][1]=65 'A'`. (It was reading "AA" from the file into `string cell;` and doing `tickers.push_back(cell)`;

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but I have this error in VS: "System::SByte" has no member "c_str" on the line `Results2->Text += p.tickers[i][j].c_str();`.

Comment: Ok so `tickers[i][j]` is a `char` not a `std::string` so it has no `c_str` member that's normal, try it on the `tickers[i]` instead without looping on the string as in my last edit.

Comment: That gets rid of that error, but gives another on the same line at the `+=`: 

Error: no opertator "+" matches these operands. Operand types are System::String ^ + const char *